# Problem with rejecting incoming call

Tags: android

I try to reject incoming call bu this code:

```
    private void ignoreCallAidl(Context context) 
{
        try
        {
                tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
                Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                m.setAccessible(true);
                telephonyService = (ITelephony)m.invoke(tm);
                telephonyService.silenceRinger();
                telephonyService.endCall();

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("App","FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony subsystem");
                Log.e("App","Exception object: "+e);
        }
}
```

But i get an error:
Exception object: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but I have solved it.

It's because you have proguarded the ITelephony from `ITelephony.aidl`. You have to filter it in the `proguard.cfg` file.

Comment: I am new to android app development. Could you please explain your answer?

Answer (score 3):

-keep class com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony { *; }

Comment: Although the top most answer gives an overview of the solution, this is the actual solution and should have been the accepted answer (just in case OP wants to mark any answer accepted).

Comment: What is the meaning of this solution? Please eloborate I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @SuryaprakashPisay I met this problem just now. Let me try to explain it. According to the error description, it most probably proguard problem. ProGuard detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes from your packaged app. In this case, it removed java.lang.ClassCastException: `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony` from you source code, so when casting, it couldn't find it hence a java.lang.ClassCastException happened.  The `keep` statement tell proguard process don't remove ITelephony, so it can be casted to.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

1. Download the ITelephony.aidl from android source repository.
2. Rename the ITelephony.aidl to ITelephony.java
3. put this file in your project src directory as /src/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.java

It will work.